# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'toString') - redis

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, redis

```
const updateLeaderboards = async () => {
  try {
    const users = await User.findAll();
    const leaderboardData = [];

    users.forEach((user) => {
      // Add user data to the leaderboardData array in the required format
      leaderboardData.push(user.totalAmount);
      leaderboardData.push(user.username);
    });

    // Store the leaderboard data as a Sorted Set in Redis
    const redisArgs = ['leaderboard', ...leaderboardData];
    console.log("redisargs #######", redisArgs);
      client.zAdd( JSON.stringify(redisArgs), (err, response) => {
      if (err) {
        console.error('An error occurred while updating leaderboard data:', err);
      } else {
        console.log('Leaderboard updated successfully in Redis.');
      }
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('An error occurred while updating leaderboard data:', error);
  }
};
```

```
redisargs ####### [ 'leaderboard', 0, 'ranjith', 500, 'vinnu', 0, 'mohan', 80, 'vinay' ]
......../@redis/client/dist/lib/commands/generic-transformers.js:51

           *return num.toString();*
                       ^

**TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'toString')**
    at transformNumberInfinityArgument 
..../node_modules/@redis/client/dist/lib/commands/generic-transformers.js:51:24)
```

Why am getting this error

Comment: There's no `num.toString()` in the code you provide.

Comment: That is an inbuilt code error @InSync

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In leaderboardData, you have a mix of integer and string. You need to convert your `user.totalAmount` into string and it will work

Answer (score 0):

The client zAdd function expects an object or array of objects with score and value ([see here](https://redis.js.org/documentation/client/functions/lib_commands_ZADD.transformArguments.html)). In your case `redisArgs` is an array

It should be like below:

```
await client.zAdd('key', { score: 1, value: 'value' })
  .zAdd('key', [{ score: 1, value: '1' }, { score: 2, value: '2' }])
  .exec()
```